# Most efficient way to search event log messages

Tags: powershell

Suppose I want to find the newest occurrence of event `4688` that contains the string `0x1278`. I am able to find the event by getting a certain number of events and then searching the message for that string:

```
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1000 -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Security";Id=4688} | Where-Object {$_.Message -match "0x1278"}
```

There are two issues with this approach:

1. The script must always wait for 1000 events to be returned, even if the event being searched for was at index 3.
2. If the event was older and would have been at index 1034, too few events were checked and it wasn't found when it should have been.

Is there a way to address these issues? Ideally the event should be found in the shortest time possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-FilterXPath` to offload filtering to the event log service!

This approach won't allow us to search the text of the rendered log message, but it *will* allow us to very granularly query structured data in the event.

Assuming that you're searching `0x1278` because it's a process ID event, we can query for that specific event with the following XPath expression:

> ```
> *[System[EventID=4688] and EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessId']='0x3e8']]
> ```

Used with `Get-WinEvent`, we end up with something like:

```
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1000 -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4688] and EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessId']='0x3e8']]" -LogName "Security"
```

Now the eventlog service only needs to return *one event*, making your `Get-WinEvent` query execute much faster

Comment: I like this approach, but if there are two events with the same value for `NewProcessId`, they're both returned. Is there a way to return only the first match? Or the newest of all matches?

Comment: Actually that shouldn't make too much of a difference. This approach returns all matches nearly instantaneously, so looping through the few results would take a negligible amount of time.

Comment: @jdgregson Returning the first X events is definitely possible, just combine with `-MaxEvents` :) Whether it takes a long time on your end (ie. in powershell), that of course depends on log volume and how far back you're looking. But being able to filter specifically on `NewProcessId` versus `LogonID` or `ProcessId` for example is the real value here, no false positives!

Comment: Ah, good point, it'd definitely be nice to guarantee the accuracy of this lookup. I'll play around with that. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: A good rule of thumb when returning large data sets is to filter as much as possible first, then return data.  You likely won't notice the gains on small result-sets but on medium-to-large result-sets, the impact can be orders of magnitude in difference.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of piping the array of events to `Where-Object`, pipe it to `ForEach-Object`, assign the first match to a variable, and then break out of the loop. If you remove the `-MaxEvents` parameter, all events will be searched until a match is found or there are no more events:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Security";id=4688} | ForEach-Object {if ($_.Message -match "0x1278") {$result = $_; break;}}
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $result


   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
2/18/2020 10:14:55 AM         4688 Information      A new process has been created....
```